# Custom Angular filter never called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array of strings which I'd like to filter by first letter using a custom angular filter.

I have the following `ng-repeat` set up:

```
<div ng-repeat="proverb in proverbs | firstLetter">
  <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
</div>
```

And this is my custom filter, currently using a default letter `"A"` for testing purposes:

```
angular
  .module('raidersApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngResource'
  ])
  .filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (input) {
      input = input || [];
      letter = "A";
      var out = [];
      input.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log("current item is", item, item.charAt(0));
        if (item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() == letter) {
           out.push(item);
        }
      });
      return out;
    };
  })
```

The problem is, this filter is currently filtering everything out (the app works and there are no console errors but the `ng-repeat` section is blank), and the `console.log` is never even being displayed.

What's missing?

Comment: Your filter works, check your "proverbs".

Comment: @DTing "Unfortunately" if I simply remove the filter the output works exactly as expected. If I add a different filter (for instance, angular's filter:query with a search input) it also works normally. So I believe it must be something with my custom filter or me not linking something somewhere.

Comment: you have no predicate argument for the filter. Create a demo showing what you want to use for `letter`

Comment: @charlietfl You mean test with firstLetter:'A' and then accept an argument in the filter function?

Comment: yes, if you really want to test it, or even better a scope variable with value = 'A'

Comment: Not working in any case. Also, console.log() never gets called anywhere inside my filter function. Not sure if that's normal behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post more of your code. Your problem is most likely an issue with how you structured your app.

Here is a similar filter that does what I think you are looking for:

```js
var app = angular.module('raidersApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.langID = "en";
    $scope.proverbs = ['Apple', 'Apricot', 'Banana', 'Orange'];
  })
  .filter('firstLetter', function() {
    return function(input, letter) {
      return (input || []).filter(function(item) {
        return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() === letter;
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="raidersApp">

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <h3>A</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="proverb in proverbs | firstLetter: 'A'">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
    <h3>O</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="proverb in proverbs | firstLetter: 'O'">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

From what I can tell your code works as is.

```js
var app = angular.module('raidersApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.langID = "en";
    $scope.proverbs = ['Apple', 'Apricot', 'Banana', 'Orange'];
  })
  .filter('firstLetter', function() {
    return function(input) {
      input = input || [];
      letter = "A";
      var out = [];
      input.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log("current item is", item, item.charAt(0));
        if (item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() == letter) {
          out.push(item);
        }
      });
      return out;
    };
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="raidersApp">

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat="proverb in proverbs | firstLetter">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay on my part. Turns out it was the filter code itself that was not working, as soon as I tried your code the filter worked immediately, without any other changes.

Answer (score 1):

Watch your syntax!

```
input.forEach()
```

was throwing an error for me..  also watch out for declaring global variables.

Try this:

```
.filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var input = input || [];
        var letter = "A";
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
            console.log("current item is", item, item.charAt(0));
            if (item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() == letter) {
                out.push(item);
            }
        });
        return out;
    };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XtFQlCWX27gEy0PeQCwv?p=preview